# ¿Guardar las categorías repetidas con sus diferentes montos de un request volley?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-volley

Estoy trabajando con android y tengo un Request con volley para mandar a pedir los movimientos que se han realizado, el json me regresa categoria y monto, quisiera que si las categorias son las mismas solo me regrese esa categoria con el monto total de todas esas mismas categorias.

Mi json es este:

```
{
"results": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "category": "Venta",
  "amount_in_cents": 100
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "category": "Venta",
  "amount_in_cents": 50
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "category": "Depositos",
  "amount_in_cents": 200
}
```

]
}

Mi consulta es:

```
JSONArray mJsonArray = response.getJSONArray("results");
                for (int i = 0; i < mJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject mJsonObject = mJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String categoria = mJsonObject.getString("category");
                    Integer amount = mJsonObject.getInt("amount_in_cents");
                }
```

Ejemplo
Categoria = (Venta,Depositos)
Amount = (150,200)

Comment: entonces la solucion seria en el servicio web que haces la consulta

Comment: El cambio tendrias que solicitarlo al proveedor del servicio para que envie como necesitas.

Comment: Estoy usando Eloquent laravel, como puedo sumar columnas con la condición del row?

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario user33.. Tenias razón, lo termine haciendo desde el servidor con una consulta!